# ¿Cómo puedo editar una tabla sin que se sobrescriban los demás datos?

Tags: javascript

Estoy editando los datos de una tabla de productos pero al guardar los datos, se sobrescribe en la ultima fila borrando las demás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al darle a aceptar los datos se cambian , pero estos son sobre puestos por que estoy usando html para introducir los datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve probando varias  formas con javascript para poder realizar el editar pero no me funciona, aun me falta mucha experiencia con este lenguaje
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este script puedo crear los input en la tabla para editar los datos y los botones que me permiten guardar o anular la edición pero como mencioné anteriormente este me sobrescribe los datos al momento de darle aceptar

```
    <script>
    var editando = false;



    function transformarEnEditable(nodo) {

        //El nodo recibido es SPAN

        if (editando == false) {

            var nodoTd = nodo.parentNode; //Nodo TD

            var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR

            var nodoContenedorForm = document.getElementById('contenedorForm'); //Nodo DIV

            var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');

            var Nombre = nodosEnTr[0].textContent;
            var Unidad = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;
            var Precio = nodosEnTr[2].textContent;
            var Cantidad = nodosEnTr[3].textContent;
            var Descuento = nodosEnTr[4].textContent;
            var Observacion = nodosEnTr[5].textContent;

            var nuevoCodigoHtml = '<td><input type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre" value="' + Nombre + '" size="15" readonly/></td>' +

                '<td><input type="text" name="Unidad" id="Unidad" value="' + Unidad + '" size="5" readonly/></td>' +

                '<td><input type="text" name="Precio" id="Precio" value="' + Precio + '" size="5" readonly/></td>' +

                '<td><input type="text" name="Cantidad" id="Cantidad" value="' + Cantidad + '" size="5"/></td>' +

                '<td><input type="text" name="Descuento" id="Descuento" value="' + Descuento + '" size="5"/></td>' +

                '<td><input type="text" name="Observacion" id="Observacion" value="' + Observacion + '" size="50"/></td> <td>En edición</td>';



            nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;



            nodoContenedorForm.innerHTML = 'Pulse Aceptar para guardar los cambios o cancelar para anularlos' +

                '<form name = "formulario" method="post" >' +

                '<input class="btn btn-info text-center" type="button" value="Aceptar" onclick="capturarEnvio()"> <input class="btn btn-info text-center" type="reset" value="Cancelar" onreset="anular()">';
           
            editando = "true";
        }

        else {
            alert('Solo se puede editar una línea. Recargue la página para poder editar otra');

        }

    }
    function capturarEnvio(nodo) {

       
        var nodoContenedorForm = document.getElementById('contenedorForm'); //Nodo DIV
        var Nomb = Nombre.value;
        var Unid = Unidad.value;
        var Prec = Precio.value;
        var Desc = Descuento.value;
        var Cant = Cantidad.value;
        var Obs = Observacion.value;

        console.log(Nomb);
        console.log(Desc);
        var nuevoProducto = '<tr class="c-table__row" id="trDato">' +
            '<td class="c-table__cell tdNombre"> ' + Nomb + '</td > ' +
            '<td class="c-table__cell tdUnidad"> ' + Unid + '</td > ' +
            '<td class="c-table__cell tdPrecio"> ' + Prec + '</td > ' +
            '<td class="c-table__cell tdCantidad"> ' + Cant + '</td > ' +
            '<td class="c-table__cell tdDescuento"> ' + Desc + '</td > ' +
            '<td class="c-table__cell tdObservacion"> ' + Obs + '</td > ' +
            '<td><button  class="btn btn-default btnEliminar"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></td>' +
            '</tr>';
        nodoContenedorForm.innerHTML = "";
        $("#tableResultContent").html(nuevoProducto);
       
    }

    function anular() {

        window.location.reload();

    }
</script>
```

Comment: que tiene que ver c# aca?

Comment: debes hacer un `nodoTr.innerHTML += nuevoCodigoHtml;` para que apendice y no sobrescriba!